# Django wrong url?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have two urls.One is for blogs and the other is for games.I have app for games and blogs.

```
path('',include('games.urls')),
   path('blog',include('blogs.urls')),
```

My gameapp url is like this:

```
path('<slug:platform>/<slug:slug>',views.oyun,name='detail'),
```

My blogapp urls are like this:

```
path('', views.blogs, name='blog'),
    path('/<slug:slug>', views.blog_id, name='blog_id'),
```

This url is going to(`path('/<slug:slug>', views.blog_id, name='blog_id')`), views.oyun so it is giving error. How can i solve this?

```
Views.py

def blogs(request):
    blogss=blog.objects.all().order_by('-created')
    return render(request,"blog.html",{"blogs":blogss})


def blog_id(request,slug):

    blog_id=blog.objects.get(seo_url=slug)



    return render(request,"blog-writings.html",{"blog_id":blog_id})

def oyun(request,platform,slug):
   oyun = Oyunlar.objects.get(slugyap=slug)


...
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem! Couldn't solve it either, so here for rez

Comment: Hello @cvsrt can you provide your error

Comment: Can you share the views behind these URL paths?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Oyunlar matching query does not exist. It is because it is going to oyun.views.Not the views.blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `detail` path will capture the URLs that are supposed to fire the `blog_id` path. Indeed, in the `games.urls` we see:

```
path('<slug:platform>/<slug:slug>',views.oyun,name='detail'),
```

whereas for the `blog_id`, the *complete* URL path is:

```
     'blog/<slug:slug>'
```

This thus means that if you visit `blog/foo`, it will fire the `oyun` view with `'blog'` as value for the `platform` variable, and `'foo'` as value for the `slug` variable.

You can swap the paths, such that it will first inspect the items with a `blog/` prefix, and only will fire the `oyun` view, if that is not the case:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('blog',include('blogs.urls')),  # ← first the blog/ paths.
    path('',include('games.urls')),
]
```